# Why am I getting multiple calls for a single item?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a call to the server to get a list of items based on a specific ID selected in a dropdown list.

html:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="parent in model.waivers">
    <td><select ng-model="parent.ID" ng-options="object.Key as object.Value for object in model.myObject"></select></td>
    <td><select ng-model="parent.ServiceNameID" ng-options="expectedResult.Key as expectedResult.Value for expectedResult in model.output(object.ID)"></select></td>
</tr>
```

controller:

```
    $scope.model.output = function(id) {
        console.log(id);
    }
```

model:

```
var Model = function() {
    this.parent = [];
};
```

I am just logging it here to see the result. what I really intend to do is get a list based on that id.

if there are 3 table rows then what is output is:

```
1
1
1
2
2
3
3
1
2
3
1
```

instead of:

```
1
2
3
```

which is what I would expect since there is only one id per line.

Any suggestions on what is causing this behavior?

**Update**

So @Fieldset informed me that the problem is caused by angular calling the method one time for each item in the parent.

Any suggestions on how to do this only calling the method once per item?

Comment: What does $scope.model look like?

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira there isn't really anything pertinent to the model. I added it but it is just a one stop place holder for all my controller specific objects

Comment: Angular needs to recheck all of it's databinding whenever it thinks something might have changed.

Comment: Your code is in a ng-repeat so `model.output(object.ID)` will be called as many times as there are elements in `model.waivers`

Comment: @Fieldset So if there are three items in the Waivers array then every line will be called 3 times each?

Comment: This is antipattern actually - you will face a lot of issues if you write like this.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov This is a one-off thing. I am trying to use angular to load the DDL instead of passing them up from the server already loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is in a ng-repeat so model.output(object.ID) will be called as many times as there are elements in model.waivers.

You can't do your request to your server like this, because your HTTP request will be asynchronous and return a promise and you can't use a promise in your view. You have to load your data in your controller ($scope), then your view will be able to access to your data through $scope

You have to request data before :

**controller**

```
function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.data = [];

  //This is asynchronous
  $http.get('my/path/to/my.data').success(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
  });

}
```

**EDIT:**

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q) {

  //One request per id
  var ids = [4, 52, 65, 12, 78];
  var promises = [];

  ids.forEach(function(id) {
    promises.push($http.get('my/path/to/my.data?id='+id));
  });



  //Fill $scope.data when all requests are done
  $scope.data = [];

  $q.all(promises).then(function(data){

    $scope.data = data;

    /**
     * You get something wich looks like
     * 
     * Assuming that your webservice returns a response like {id: 4, name: 'Something'}
     * 
     * $scope.data = [
     *  {id: 4, name: 'Something'},
     *  {id: 52, name: 'Something else'},
     *  {id: 65, name: 'foo'},
     *  {id: 12, name: 'bar'},
     *  {id: 78, name: 'foobar'}
     * ];
     * 
     * So you can loop over $scope.data in your view
     * 
     */

  });

});
```

Comment: I only have to id in the current iteration of the loop, how do i pass that id to the service/controller so that I only get the list based on the selected id?